# How can a I use the window.print method in a WebView with react-native

Tags: webview, react-native, react-native-webview

I'm using react-native and its webview to call a webpage where at the end of a flow of four or five pages, they use the window.print method to print the page. But, when I tap the button to print the page nothing happens. Do you know what can I do in this situation to make the button work?. I've only tried this in Android and I use "react-native-webview": "^5.10.0" with "react-native": "^0.59.9".

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am also looking for the same

Comment: any solution? anyone?

Answer (score -2):

I am using a work around for now as my react native webview app only consists of the uri of the web app. What I am doing is I am checking if `window.ReactNativeWebView` exists or not. If yes, then do `window.ReactNativeWebView.print()` so for my app it takes me to the external browser of that device and there since `window.ReactNativeWebView` doesn't exists, I do `window.print()`.

I am not sure if this is the right way to do but if someone has a better solution. I am eagerly waiting for it!